# How checking lookup depth into nested dictionary as class attribute?

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, attributes

I created a nested dictionary based on `AttrDict` found there :

[Object-like attribute access for nested dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38034377/object-like-attribute-access-for-nested-dictionary)

I modified it to contain `str` commands in "leaves" that gets executed when the value is requested/written to :

```
commands = {'root': {'com': {'read': 'READ_CMD', 'write': 'WRITE_CMD'} } }

class AttrTest()
    def __init__:
        self.__dict__['attr'] = AttrDict(commands)

test = AttrTest()
data = test.attr.root.com.read    # data = value read with the command
test.attr.root.com.write = data   # data = value written on the com port
```

While it works beautifully, I'd like to :

- Avoid people getting access to `attr`/`root`/`com` as these returns a sub-level dictonary
- People accessing `attr.root.com` directly (through `__getattribute__`/`__setattr__`)

Currently, I'm facing the following problems :

- As said, when accessing the 'trunk' of the nested dict, I get a partial dict of the 'leaves'
- When accessing `attr.root.com` it returns `{'read': 'READ_CMD', 'write': 'WRITE_CMD'}`
- If detecting a `read` I do a forward lookup and return the value, but then `attr.root.com.read` fails

Is it possible to know what is the final level Python will request in the "path" ?

- To block access to `attr`/`root`
- To read/write the value accessing `attr.root.com` directly (using forward lookup)
- To return the needed partial dict only if `attr.root.com.read` or `attr.root.com.write` are requested

Currently I've found nothing that allows me to control how deep the lookup is expected to go.

Thanks for your consideration.

Answer (score 0):

For a given attribute lookup you cannot determine how many others will follow; this is how Python works. In order to resolve `x.y.z`, first the object `x.y` needs to be retrieved before the subsequent attribute lookup `(x.y).z` can be performed.

What you can do however, is return a proxy object that represents the (partial) path instead of the actual underlying object which is stored in the dict. So for example if you did `test.attr.com` then this would return a proxy object which represents the path `attr.com` to-be-looked up on the `test` object. Only when you encounter a `read` or `write` leaf in the path, you would resolve the path and read/write the data.

The following is a sample implementation which uses an `AttrDict` based on `__getattr__` to provide the `Proxy` objects (so you don't have to intercept `__getattribute__`):

```
from functools import reduce


class AttrDict(dict):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return Proxy(self, (name,))

    def _resolve(self, path):
        return reduce(lambda d, k: d[k], path, self)


class Proxy:
    def __init__(self, obj, path):
        object.__setattr__(self, '_obj', obj)
        object.__setattr__(self, '_path', path)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Path<{'.'.join(self._path)}>"

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name == 'read':
            return self._obj._resolve(self._path)[name]
        else:
            return type(self)(self._obj, (*self._path, name))

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if name != 'write' or name not in (_dict := self._obj._resolve(self._path)):
            raise AttributeError(f'Cannot set attribute {name!r} for {self}')
        _dict[name] = value


commands = {'root': {'com': {'read': 'READ_CMD', 'write': 'WRITE_CMD'} } }

test = AttrDict({'attr': commands})
print(f'{test.attr = !s}')                # Path<attr>
print(f'{test.attr.root = !s}')           # Path<attr.root>
print(f'{test.attr.root.com = !s}')       # Path<attr.root.com>
print(f'{test.attr.root.com.read = !s}')  # READ_CMD
test.attr.root.com.write = 'test'
test.attr.root.write = 'illegal'  # raises AttributeError
```