# Alternatives to attrdict library for nested AttrDict

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, nested-attributes

My program contains a lot of configuration parameters so I was looking for a way to have them all in one place, accessible from every file in the project.
I thought about a config module which would act as an interface to a yaml file that contains the configuration parameters. One requirement I want is to be able to access the config object with attribute (dot) notation. I found the [`AttrDict`](https://pypi.org/project/attrdict/) library and wrote the following code:

```
import yaml
from attrdict import AttrDict


def get_cfg():
    return cfg_node


def dump(out_filepath):
    with open(out_filepath, 'w') as file:
        yaml.dump(attrdict_to_dict(cfg_node), file)


def load_yaml(filepath):
    global cfg_node
    with open(filepath, 'r') as file:
        cfg_node = dict_to_attrdict(yaml.safe_load(file))


def attrdict_to_dict(myAttrdict):
    dictionary = dict(myAttrdict)
    for k in myAttrdict:
        value = dictionary[k]
        if isinstance(value, AttrDict):
            dictionary[k] = attrdict_to_dict(value)
    return dictionary


def dict_to_attrdict(dictionary):
    myAttrdict = AttrDict()
    for k in dictionary:
        value = dictionary[k]
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            myAttrdict.__setattr__(k, attrdict_to_dict(value))
    return myAttrdict


cfg_node = AttrDict()
cfg_node.b = "value_b"
cfg_node.a = AttrDict()
cfg_node.a.b = AttrDict()
cfg_node.a.c = "nested_c"
cfg_node.a.b.e= "double_nested_e"
```

The problem is that this library does not allow nested AttrDict().

```
print(cfg_node)
 >>> {'b': 'value_b', 'a': AttrDict({})}
```

However if I do the following, nested assignment works but I'm forced to explicitly use the nested object which is not useful for my purpose:

```
cfg_node = AttrDict()
cfg_node.b = "value_b"
a =  AttrDict()
a.c = "nested_value_c"
cfg_node.a = a
print(cfg_node)
 >>> {'b': 'value_b', 'a': AttrDict({'c':'nested_value_c'})}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've looked into the documentation of [AttrDict](https://pypi.org/project/attrdict/) and I'm afraid that recursive attribute access is not possible. See here:

> Recursive attribute access results in a shallow copy, so recursive
> assignment will fail (as you will be writing to a copy of that
> dictionary):
>
> ```
> > attr = AttrDict('foo': {})
> > attr.foo.bar = 'baz'
> > attr.foo
> {}
> ```

They suggest using an [AttrMap](https://pypi.org/project/attrmap/#description) instead. However I've tried using it and I was getting an error right from the import. I'll look into it. *update below

For now, what you can do is define instead your custom `AttrDict`.

```
class AttrDict(dict):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AttrDict, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.__dict__ = self


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cfg_node = AttrDict()
    cfg_node.b = "value_b"
    cfg_node.a = AttrDict()
    cfg_node.a.b = AttrDict()
    cfg_node.a.c = "nested_c"
    cfg_node.a.b.e = "double_nested_e"
    print(cfg_node)
    print(cfg_node.a.b.e)
```

The output here is, as you needed:

```
{'b': 'value_b', 'a': {'b': {'e': 'double_nested_e'}, 'c': 'nested_c'}}
double_nested_e
```

If you are using an IDE you will also get code completion while you access the keys of `AttrDict`.

See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38034377/14774959), there are additional methods you can add to the custom class that can enhance its functionalities.

Hope this helps!

**Update** on the AttrMap library. I've asked about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73333512/14774959), I was using python 3.8 but the library contains a `list[str]`, which is available only on python >= 3.9.

**Second update** on AttrMap. The creator has fixed the issue in the new version, now it supports python 3.6

Answer (score 1):

## Representing Configuration in Code

I like [pydantic](https://pypi.org/project/pydantic/) and [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) for such use-cases. I feel like pydantic makes it incredible clean and easy.

```py
from datetime import datetime
from typing import List, Optional
from pydantic import BaseModel

class User(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name = 'John Doe'
    signup_ts: Optional[datetime] = None
    friends: List[int] = []
```

You can create the objects just like normal objects, parse it from a JSON / YAML (or anything that creates a dict). You can have validation logic and data transformations.

## Attribute-like access

If it's just about making quick objects: [`types.SimpleNamespace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.SimpleNamespace):

```
from types import SimpleNamespace

sn = SimpleNamespace(param_a='1')
print(sn.param_a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the module [attridict](https://pypi.org/project/attridict/), if offers what you are looking for.
It 100% allows for nested dicts.
It basically works the same

```
> att = attridict({'foo': {}})
> att.foo.bar = 'baz'
> att.foo
{'bar':'baz'}
```