# import attrmap gives TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to use the library [`AttrMap`](https://pypi.org/project/attrmap/#description) which is suggested as an alternative to [`AttrDict`](https://pypi.org/project/attrdict/) library. From the documentation of AttrDict:

> ... If either of these caveats are deal-breakers, or you don’t need
> your object to be a dict, consider using AttrMap instead.

I installed it with `pip install attrmap` and imported it in a fresh conda environment, as usual with `import attrmap`.

However the import gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import attrmap
  File "/Users/claudia/opt/anaconda3/envs/test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/attrmap/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .attrmap import AttrMap, AttributeMap, AttrMapping, AttributeMapping
  File "/Users/claudia/opt/anaconda3/envs/test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/attrmap/attrmap.py", line 12, in <module>
    class AttrMap(object):
  File "/Users/claudia/opt/anaconda3/envs/test/lib/python3.8/site-packages/attrmap/attrmap.py", line 91, in AttrMap
    def keys(self) -> list[str]:
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable
```

I've already tried installing different previous versions and adding the import in a Colab notebook, all with same error.

Does anyone knows what the issue might be? I don't think is related to my environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`list[str]` is a type annotation available since python 3.9, the traceback shows your system uses python 3.8, try upgrading your python or downgrading attrmap.

It might be worth reporting this issue to the attrmap developer.

Comment: Great! I've tried downgrading to previous versions, but there are only three and none of those works. Upgrading to python 3.9 works perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Now the bug is fixed in the latest version as introduced in the [github](https://github.com/YiqunChen1999/attrmap). You can try to update to the latest version. It supports python>=3.6 now.

Comment: Wonderful, I confirm that it works!